Blender Error Installing Pytorch
I am trying to install PyTorch offline into Blender version 4.3. My steps are as follows:

I download all the wheel files onto my machine using:
pip3 download torch torchvision torchaudio


I type in my Blender Python console
bpy.utils.user_resource("SCRIPTS", path="modules")
to get the path to the module's directory in my installation of Blender on my machine.

In Blender, I run the following lines in my python script below to install all of my wheel files that I received from 1 and using the file directory obtained from 2. Not shown is me importing the sys, os and subprocess files and changing my directory to where I have stored my wheel files.:


After the script is completed, I'm able to import into python all the modules installed except for import torch, torchvision or torchaudio. Below is the error that I get:


>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Lance\AppData\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.3\scripts\modules\torch\__init__.py", line 262, in <module>
    _load_dll_libraries()
  File "C:\Users\Lance\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.3\scripts\modules\torch\__init__.py", line 258, in _load_dll_libraries
    raise err
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\Lance\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.3\scripts\modules\torch\lib\torch_python.dll" or one of its dependencies.


Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you so much for the help.

There is a functional installation method of pip packages on the following topic: python - Install pip and packages from within Blender OS independently - Blender Stack Exchange. If this doesn't solve your issue, please [edit] your question to update what you tried and how it didn't help, it will queue it up for reopening.
